# Create a MS Word doc based on a template, changing specific parts of it using user provided values

Tags: ms-word, c#-6.0, .net-4.6.1, file-generation

I need to dynamically generate contracts, and for that our HR depart already has some specific templates which only need a few changes (like names, address, phone number, etc).

For that reason, I'm looking for a library that will help me with the following:

1. Read a word file (used as a template)
2. Identify specially marked pieces of text, and replace them.

Do you know of any library(preferably free) that will help achieve that?

P.S. The .Net Framework I'm using is 4.6.1

Comment: Requesting libraries, etc. is off-topic on Stack Overflow... There are lots of examples of this kind of code "out there". As long as the template is set up correctly it's not really a big problem, nor does it require lots of code.

Comment: Yes, but all of them either use Interop or OpenXML and I want to avoid using them. Specially the former.

Comment: I didn't know it was off-topic to ask for a library. And if you think I should close/delete this question, you could have said so. No need to upvote the question :(

Comment: What do you think a library would do differently? It certainly will also use the "Interop" or Open XML.

Comment: Things that are off-topic can be found listed at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. The question can be deleted, but first you might want to clarify why you think you need a library.

Comment: For example for Excel we have ClosedXML which will let us specify variables (using curly brackets) to later easily replace them.

Comment: That certainly also uses the Open XML file format. So what you mean is something that (from your POV) makes your life simpler? (I'm so steeped in Word I find it really easy to just write the code - different perspective...) Yes, I'd say you can delete this question and ask it somewhere else that doesn't have the same restrictions as SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [WordprocessingDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument).